# Unexpected crash in Safari with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on a scrollable timeline rendered in the HTML5 canvas.
I've already developed most of the features but I've noticed unexpected crashes on Safari (doesn't crash in chrome and firefox), so I've removed all the features (leaving just the very basic timeline) to verify that this won't change the situation.

Here you may see a demo of the timeline (reduced to the basic building blocks which seems to cause the crash): http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/uUQtH/3/

You may click and drag to scroll thru the days and, if you un-comment some lines of code, you'll also see days and months numbers.

Try to scroll the timeline from left to right, repeat that until you should get your browser to crash (you may need to force an exit).

this is the error I get before the crash:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'g.ctx.lineTo(x, g.height / 1.4)')
```

it always looks like `g.ctx.lineTo` works fine but, without any apparent reason, it stop working. You may try to log `x` or `g.height / 1.4` but you'll see the crashes are not consistent with these values.

Also, if you un-comment the lines printing the year and month, the error reported by the browser will not be the same. This means that **clearly the crash has nothing to do with the functions responsable of the rendering itself**.

**Possible reason**: too much CPU required.

Because of how it's implemented, all of the parts of the timeline which are outside of the screen are considered in the loop (even if not rendered) {this only applies to the parts of the timeline which goes outside of the screen from the *left*, not from the *right*}. I wasn't able to avoid it. So, it could be that the more you scroll on the right the longer to complete the loop becomes (until javascript stops you). This is a super-simplified pseudocode version of the draw loop:

```
start = 0;

function draw(){
    day = 0;

    for (x = start; x <= screen.width; x += 10, d += 1){

        // check if first day of the month
        if (d days from now is 1)
            draw long line at position x
        else
            draw short line at position x

    }
}

function mouseDragging(){

    // users dragging mouse cursor
    // start changes accordingly but always stays minor than 0

}
```

as you can see, `start` will get to very low values pretty fast (if the user wants to) making the draw loop very long to complete. Could this be the reason of the crash? I don't think it is: **usually when I program long loops the computer start to lag, but it never throws errors in the console and crash all at once**. However, that's the only possible reason I see.

Comment: I tested it in Chrome (on Linux). No crashing here. Scrolled for ages, too. (CPU stayed lowed)

Comment: Thanks for your report! Tested again on Safari, 10 seconds of scrolling till I see the loading cursor and I'm not able to move anything in the browser unless I force quit.

Comment: no crashes under FireFox - this is getting crazier...

Comment: I tested on Safari 6.0.2 and OSX 10.7, and it didn't crash (I scrolled a lot, and tried uncommenting the lineTo lines too). Which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: 5.1.7 on OSX 10.6.8 - seriously, whats going on?! I'm preparing a video right now...

Comment: here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2eFj4RuHXA
at minute 0:50 I start to see the spinning pinwheel, it doesn't appear in the video thou... I'm no longer able to select text, scroll the graph or do anything other than forcing the quit.
50 seconds, sometimes it takes even less...